# Flutter Snackbar is displaying below bottom sheet

Tags: flutter

I have a login dialogue in bottomSheet. I want to show a snackbar when an error occurs. But When I show the snackbar it goes below the BottomSheet Dialogue and thus not visible.

Is there any way that I can show the Snackbar above bottomSheet
This gif show when I click on Login button no snackbar appears but when I dismiss the bottomSheet then I can see a snack bar there. I want to be able to see the snackbar while the bottomSheet is Visble. Please Help!

I'm using scaffoldKey for displaying **snackbar** and **bottomSheet** Dialogue.

```
scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackbar(_mySnackbar);
```

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It is possible through creating another scaffold in your bottom sheet and call showSnackbar using the key of your new Scaffold.

But don't know if we can display the snackbar over/above bottomSheet using only one Scaffold

Comment: I did not try it but you can try if it could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825502/10329023