# Flutter shrink Scaffold to fit children for transparent modal

Tags: flutter, dart

`showModalBottomSheet` requires that the content be wrapped in a `Scaffold` to avoid glitches like SnackBars rendering behind the modal, not to mention it appears to be best practice. But then the sheet takes up the whole screen and cannot shrink to fit only its content.

- Using `Scaffold` does not shrink to fit the content
- Not using `Scaffold` breaks framework functionality and best practices

```dart
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
      return BottomModal();
    },
  );

class BottomModal extends HookWidget {
  const BottomModal({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( // Scaffold is required for anything relating to navigation and without it framework functionality breaks
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Modal")),
      body: SizedBox(height: Random().nextInt(151) + 250), // Scaffold needs to shrink to whatever height to fit this content
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679737/show-a-snackbar-above-modal-bottom-sheet

Comment: It's not similar. I am trying to do things correctly and use Scaffold and resize it, not jumping at any hack possible. I addressed in the question that there are answers which do not use Scaffold which are inherently flawed. This question made it clear that I am not willing to use hacks. The part about why I am needing this is extra information for background. The question I asked is how to shrink Scaffold to fit children which is not the same as the question you linked and the answers to that question would not be applicable on this one.

Comment: They're not 'hacks', they're just workarounds to make the function work :) nothing wrong with combining widgets differently. If any of those don't work, atleast provide us a code sample that we can troubleshoot

Comment: Anything that makes desired functionality without fixing the ACTUAL issue is a hack.

Comment: I'm afraid Scaffold simply isn't designed to shrink to content. At least I also can't find a way to do it. If the height is fixed you could simply wrap the Scaffold in a SizedBox, but dynamically determining the height probably requires more hacky workarounds

Comment: Then this is a framework problem, perhaps I can report it. Modals are navigation-based and without Scaffold then you get a plethora of weird bugs. But if we cannot shrink to fit then the possibility of modals with transparent background is rendered impossible. We cannot just go setting the percentage of the screen to magic numbers because someone with a small phone screen will then break. The ideal behaviour is for it to shrink to content with a max height of a percentage of the screen, and then within that use a scrollview if the content is bigger than that. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Karatekid430 well, I don't know if my confirmation is worth anything because I'm also just a fellow developer like you. Maybe more expert flutter developers do know of a valid way to do it

Answer (score 0):

the size is wrong probably because the widget you put in the builder section of showModalBottomSheet is `Column` or other Widget that takes the maximum height

if the case is `Column` you can add the property `mainAxisSize` and set it to `MainAxisSize.min`

like this:

```
  onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                isScrollControlled: true,  //enables the modal to be any size
                  context: context, builder: (context)
              =>
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                // insert your widgets here
                ],
              )); 
            },
```

Edit:

If Scaffold has to be used this is a possible solution:
after the first frame is rendered using a global key we can get the child's height and set the parents height accordingly

```
class BottomModal extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomModal({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomModal> createState() => _BottomModalState();
}

class _BottomModalState extends State<BottomModal> {
  final GlobalKey _childKey = GlobalKey();
  double parentHeight = double.infinity;


  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final childSize = _childKey.currentContext?.size ?? Size(double.infinity, double.infinity);
      print("Child size: $childSize");

      setState(() {
        // Adjust the parent size based on the child size
        parentHeight = childSize.height; // Adjust as needed
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: parentHeight,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          key: _childKey,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              height:  Random().nextInt(151) + 250,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('hello')),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('press'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The widget is Scaffold because that is required by any pages relating to navigation

Comment: hmm i see,

is the content there dynamic? what i mean by that: is the size of that scaffold would change over time or from the moment its rendered it will stay the same size?

Comment: It can change, not because I am specifically doing it, but on narrower screens things can end up needing more vertical space. But for completeness it is worth finding the dynamic answer.

Comment: maybe I didn't phrase it right.
the problem with showModalButtomSheet is that you call it once, and after the initial call its size stays the same. so as long as the initial size of the Scaffolds body is dynamic its all good.

ill edit my answer and see if it works in your case

Comment: I found something that works well enough to get it in front of an audience, but in my own words it's a hack that does not solve the Scaffold not being able to shrink.

Comment: updated the answer, tell me if it fits your needs